# Topic Modeling using Mallet Java Api?

Tags: java, mallet

Hi i have to do topic modeling using Mallet Java API but i am new to coding so i am finding it real difficult to understand the Java libraries and use them. Does anyone has some sample code where they do topic modeling using the API which can be used to build upon?

Comment: Java is not an acronym. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

For an example showing how to use the Java API to import data, train models, and infer topics for new documents, see the [topic model developer's guide](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics-devel.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to some examples here:  ./mallet-2.0.7/src/cc/mallet/examples

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the tutorial slides from page 97 onwards [here](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/mallet-tutorial.pdf)

Also, take a look at my answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379106/1042409)